# How to use LINQ Group By with Count

Tags: linq, entity-framework, group-by

I want to convert the following SQL Query into Entity Framework + LINQ query. There are three tables Brands, Products and ProductReviews. Products table has BrandId as FK and ProductReviews has ProductId as FK.

```
SELECT Top 5 b.Id, b.ShortName, COUNT(r.Id) AS TotalReviews
FROM ProductsReviews r 
INNER JOIN Products p ON r.ProductId = p.Id
INNER JOIN Brands b ON p.BrandId = b.Id
GROUP BY b.Id, b.ShortName
Order By TotalReviews desc
```

Basically, I want to display top 5 brands based on the reviews posted for the products of those brands. I want output like below:

```
Id    ShortName         TotalReviews 
-----------------------------------------
76    Adidas            61
120   Yamaha            29
109   Tommy Hilfiger    26
61    Mothercare        25
31    Haier             22
```

Comment: if you found a useful answer it is recommend to accept a answer so that the users will be encouraged to answer more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pseudocode

```
var results = 
     ( from r in ProductsReviews 
       join p in Products  on r.ProductId equals p.Id
       join b in Brands  on p.BrandId equals b.Id
       group c by new { 
                   b.Id, 
                   b.ShortName } into grp
       select new {
                   Id = grp.key.Id, 
                   ShortName = grp.key.ShortName, 
                   TotalReviews = grp.Count()}
     )
    .OrderBy(x=>x.TotalReviews).Take(5);
```

Comment: Thanks @HaBo, your pseudocode helped me alot in solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how your model is setup with EF.
If you have added relations in your model, the query could be as simple as

```
var result = context.ProductReviews.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalReviews).Select(x => new { x.BrandId, X.Brand.ShortName, x.TotalReviews});
```

Because you are not selecting anything from Product, I am not including it in the query. If you have relationships in your EF, we would be able to use navigation properties such as x.Brand.Someproperty, and EF will handle creating the query based upon the model that you have setup.

the result variable will contain the query and once you access the values, the query will be executed. Lastly to only select the top 5 you would simply use the Take function like so

```
var result = context.ProductReviews.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalReviews).Select(x => new { x.BrandId, X.Brand.ShortName, x.TotalReviews}).Take(5);
```

Regards

Louis

Comment: question is asking for Group By expression. Your example will not do Group By.

Comment: sorry my bad, I thought the person was looking to migrate code from SQL to Linq, and instead of looking for a 100% code match, he was rather looking to get the same result, just using Linq and EF. Besides that the resulting sql of my query has less joins than yours and in fact executes a bit faster as a result thereof, having a single line easily readable and reproducible does still make sense to me, it also makes great use of what EF and Linq have to offer. To quote the questioner: "I want outputs like below"